# Plotting Ground Track of Elliptical Orbit with Inclination Angle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

I am trying to project the ground path of an Elliptical orbit with an arbitrary inclination angle of $\Delta i$ and a period of $T$. I have all the parameters of the orbit (semi-major axis length, semi-minor axis length, eccentricity, apogee and perigee velocity, energy, etc.).

The approach I was taking was plotting a position of the satellite in the elliptical orbit on an X-Y plane. I iterate through the time domain $t \in [0,\textrm{T}]$ where T is the period of the orbit with a specified time step of $\Delta t$. For each time, I calculate the mean anomaly and the magnitude of the distance between the satellite and the center body, $r$. When projecting the position vector of the satellite with respect to the center body on the semi-major axis, the length of that projected vector will be defined as $x$. After finding $x$, I found the vertical projection of that same position vector, thus forming the triangle below.

[image: Projection Triangle]

First of all, I need to find mean anomaly as a function of time. My code is currently not working, but in theory what I am doing is (from Curtis's *Orbital Mechanics for Engineering Students, 1st Edition*) I am solving numerically for a quantity labeled as $E$ using the equation for mean anomaly (eqn. between 3.12 and 3.13 for those who have the book), given as:
$M_e = E - e\sin(E)$. From there, I solve numerically for true anomaly using eqn. 3.7a:

$M_e = 2\arctan{(\sqrt{\frac{1-e}{1+e}}\tan{\theta/2})} - \frac{e\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin\theta}{1+e\cos\theta}$.

After finding those distances, I found the spherical coordinates of the satellite with respect to the center of the center body. $r$ would be $r_p + x$, $\phi$ would simply be the complement of $\Delta i$. $\theta$ would be the true anomaly.

After that, I plot (x,y) using spherical-cartesian transformation, but I simply do not believe that it is that straightforward. For one, what I am essentially trying to do is projecting a 3D curve onto a sphere and then projecting that onto a 2D plane. If anyone has sources/reading material on how to actually do this math, that would be fantastic. I was referencing this chapter from a book on satellites: http://fgg-web.fgg.uni-lj.si/~/mkuhar/Pouk/SG/Seminar/Vrste_tirnic_um_Zemljinih_sat/Orbit_and_Ground_Track_of_a_Satellite-Capderou2005.pdf. Unfortunately I cannot reference other equations that the book references until I get it.

I have not gotten the code to run yet, so I do not know what my plots look like but from preliminary data, it does not seem to be going in the right way (e.g. True anomaly ($\theta$) should be going from 0 to $2\pi$ as time increases, but that is not what is outputting.

EDIT: Typos and to clarify, I do not want to use external packages such as STK. I want to be able to physically come up with these plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first attach a right-handed coordinate system to the orbit, defined by the unit basis vectors $(\boldsymbol{e}_x, \boldsymbol{e}_y, \boldsymbol{e}_z)$, with $\boldsymbol{e}_x$ and $\boldsymbol{e}_y$ in the orbital plane and $\boldsymbol{e}_x$ in the direction of periapsis. First, compute the eccentric anomaly $E$ from the mean anomaly $M$:
$$
M = \frac{2\pi t}{T} = E - \sin E,
$$
assuming that the satellite is at periapsis at $t=0$. The position vector of the satellite is then given by
$$
\boldsymbol{r} = a(\cos E -e)\,\boldsymbol{e}_x + b\sin E\,\boldsymbol{e}_y.
$$
There's no need to compute the true anomaly.

Next we need to find the general transformation from the orbital frame to a given reference frame, defined by $(\boldsymbol{e}_x', \boldsymbol{e}_y', \boldsymbol{e}_z')$. This can be done using three [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) $\Omega$, $i$, and $\omega$:

- $\Omega$ is the longitude of the ascending node in the ($\boldsymbol{e}_x'$, $\boldsymbol{e}_y'$) plane, i.e. the angle measured from $\boldsymbol{e}_x'$ to the ascending node;
- $i$ is the inclination of the orbit with the ($\boldsymbol{e}_x'$, $\boldsymbol{e}_y'$) plane;
- $\omega$ is the argument of periapsis, i.e. the angle measured from the ascending node to the periapsis.

[image]

See also the [wiki article on orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements). The transformation is then given by three rotations:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{e}_x\\ \boldsymbol{e}_y\\ \boldsymbol{e}_z
\end{pmatrix}
\!=\!
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\omega & \!\sin\omega & \!0 \\
-\sin\omega & \!\cos\omega & \!0 \\
0 & \!0 & \!1
\end{pmatrix}\!
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \!0 & \!0 \\
0 & \!\cos i & \!\sin i \\
0 & \!-\sin i & \!\cos i
\end{pmatrix}\!
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\Omega & \!\sin\Omega & \!0 \\
-\sin\Omega & \!\cos\Omega & \!0 \\
0 & \!0 & \!1
\end{pmatrix}\!
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{e}_x'\\ \boldsymbol{e}_y'\\ \boldsymbol{e}_z'
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or explicitly,
$$
\boldsymbol{e}_x = (\cos\Omega\cos\omega - \sin\Omega\sin\omega\cos i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_x' + (\sin\Omega\cos\omega + \cos\Omega\sin\omega\cos i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_y' + (\sin\omega\sin i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_z'\\[1em]
\boldsymbol{e}_y = (-\cos\Omega\sin\omega - \sin\Omega\cos\omega\cos i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_x' + (-\sin\Omega\sin\omega + \cos\Omega\cos\omega\cos i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_y' + (\cos\omega\sin i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_z'\\[1em]
\boldsymbol{e}_z = (\sin\Omega\sin i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_x' + (-\cos\Omega\sin i)\,\boldsymbol{e}_y' + \cos i\,\boldsymbol{e}_z'.
$$
This enables you to express $\boldsymbol{r}$ in the reference frame coordinates. For the projected path, simply set the $z'$ component to zero.

Answer (score 1):

How /is/ True Anomaly varying in your results? If it's varying from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, it might be okay, and merely a result of the  computer restricting the ranges of the various trigonometric functions automatically.

You shouldn't need to solve numerically for True Anomaly ($\theta$) from Mean Anomaly (M). It is fairly straightforward to pull it from Eccentric Anomaly (E), and Orbital Eccentricity (e) once you have those values.

When I was working on a program to run Kepler's equations a few years ago, there were several things I did: First and foremost, for elliptical orbits, I would rectify the value I had for Mean Anomaly into the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ , which allowed for more code reuse when I did the version that dealt with hyperbolic orbits.

Given that assumption, the range on Eccentric Anomaly will also be $(-\pi,\pi]$, with the same signs as Mean Anomaly.

And that allows you to pull True Anomaly on the elliptical orbit with the following equation:

$$\theta = \pm arctan\left({\frac{\sqrt{1+e}}{\sqrt{1-e}}tan\frac{E}{2}}\right)$$

Pick the value of True Anomaly that has the same sign that the Eccentric Anomaly did. The result will, as with the other Anomalies, be in the range $(-\pi , \pi]$

If you truly need the value of True Anomaly in the range $(0,2\pi)$, you can subsequently add $2\pi$ to all negative values of $\theta$.